Flutter: Storing Feed Post in Riverpod State
I have a feed page (similar to instagram with pictures/captions). Right now, the way my code is at the moment, I fetch the data from firebase every time the user clicks on the feed screen (in bottom navigator). This means that every time they go from profile or search screen back to feed screen, it loads for a few seconds while fetching the data from firebase.
Bottom Navigator:

Obviously there are multiple issues:

Making many calls to the database
Making the user wait a few seconds every time they go to the feed page

I was thinking about using Riverpod to store the post information and only reload if there is a new post in the database. I wanted to hear people's thoughts on if this is an ok to do things, or will that take up a lot of memory. If there is a bette way as well, please share!
